# How to disable creating links for content types?

Tags: views

I don't want my slideshow text and image to be accessible in url (it is a contentype called slider).

Because normaly nobody will access that, but if he knows the url he can access that and also google bot etc.

I am using this content type only in Views Block.

I don't need pages.

How to do that?

Any module or template?

Comment: Could it be set somewhere here? admin/structure/types/manage/slider/display ?

Comment: I need completely disable creating url for this content type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use the [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module in this situation.

> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its
>   own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel.
>   Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own
>   page, through node/xxx.

You can set redirects from the pages too, so you can add a 301 or a 404 (for example)